# Create RxJS of observable from Electron ipcMain on response

Tags: rxjs, electron, reactive-programming

Creating an observable using sendSync is easy. I'd like to create an ***of*** observable using ipcMain.***on*** without using a simple callback.

```
return of(this.electronService.ipcRenderer.sendSync(channel.IPCMAIN_REQUEST_DATA));
```

Something similar, but not working.

```
return this.electronService.ipcRenderer.on(channel.IPCMAIN_RESPONSE_DATA, (event , response) => {
  return of(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
return (new Observable(subscriber=>{
    this.electronService.ipcRenderer.on(channel.IPCMAIN_RESPONSE_DATA, (event , response) => {
      subscriber.next(response)
    });
}));
```

If the event is fired then the observable will emit a new value

Comment: Didn't work but I think your on the right track. Probably a problem with my code. +1 for the help. Happy New Year :)

Comment: remember that this code is executed after the subscription to the observable

this.electronService.ipcRenderer.on

Comment: The data is definitively there. My question was how to return the data/array back to the Angular component using an of observable. Since ipcMain/on returns a callback(event, msg), not sure I can. Reverted to using a promise something much more elegant than a callback to update my component. Works equally well.

Comment: the observable do it, in your angular component you cant do it like that

nameOfYourFunctionThatReturnTheObservable().subscribe(yourDataArray=>{console.log(dataArray)}), you cant use of, because the of(as i understand) works with known values, and your data array is a future value(unknown) but for your angular component theres no difference between of operator and new Observable, both are observables in after of all. sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing the Observable like this (rxjs 5):

```
return Observable.fromEvent(ipcRenderer, channelName, (event, payload) => payload);
```

It should remove the listener when you unsubscribe the Observable.